# how can i get this black bar in css for calendar formed by a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a calendar formed by a table. Let the table be having any css or no css.

Can you please make that masking effect in css.[image]

Comment: share your code tha you have tried...

Comment: when should it mask??

Comment: you can apply CSS to a `span`  and then use `position:absolute` to place it

Comment: Leave the code. Just a table with td s and a span(if required).

Comment: @sanjeevshetty: While code is not mandatory for every question (there are some which can stand without the code), you should atleast show us what you've tried. SO as you'd know is not free code-writing service. Having said that, I find your question interesting (and potentially helpful for others in future) and so I've added a CSS implementation as answer. I would leave any JS parts for you to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do  this using pseudo-elements like in the below snippet. The bar can be thought of as having three parts - one cell where the bar starts, the one that are in the middle and the cell where it ends. By assigning the appropriate classes to the elements and by setting the required value to `border-radius` of the pseudo-elements, the bar can be created.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr, td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
td {
  position: relative;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
td[class^='select'] {
  color: white;
}
td[class^='select']:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  width: calc(100% + 4px);
  background: black;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
}
td.select-mid:before {
  left: 0px;
}
td.select-start:before {
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  left: 0px;
}
td.select-end:before {
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  left: -4px;
}
td.select-start.select-end:before {
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class='select-start'>2</td>
    <td class='select-mid'>3</td>
    <td class='select-end'>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class='select-start'>2</td>
    <td class='select-mid'>3</td>
    <td class='select-mid'>4</td>
    <td class='select-end'>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='select-start'>1</td>
    <td class='select-mid'>2</td>
    <td class='select-mid'>3</td>
    <td class='select-mid'>4</td>
    <td class='select-end'>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='select-start'>1</td>
    <td class='select-end'>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='select-start select-end'>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you .. I will try it. :)